# Opening nested project folder in IntelliJ IDEA / PyCharm / PHPStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm

IntelliJ software has been doing something really annoying lately...I have a directory structure as follows:

A/
..B/
....C/

Let's say dir C contains my IDEA project. If I want to open that project, in IntelliJ, I go to File > Open and I see folder A listed, except there's no option to go into folder A. The only option is Choose, which opens folder A as if it's a project. Then, luckily since the File > Open dialogue saves the last folder I opened, I close A, then I am able to open B, then I close B, and then finally I can open C. This also happens in PyCharm and PHPStorm so I'm thinking this is not just isolated to a bug in one version of IDEA.

I'm using IDEA 13.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.4. Anyone else see the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7, and I can open the directories by double-clicking on them via `File > Open` of Pycharm. There's no way indeed to do that with the keyboard, since the button can only `Choose` which is a shame given their keyboard-centric policy I agree.

Comment: I've tried double clicking, instead of entering the directory like you'd expect, it opens the directory up as a project, even though it's not

Comment: Do you have a .idea folder in A/ or B/ directories ? (it is hidden in the Finder)

Comment: Sorry forget it, actually I can open via double-click even my project folders. No clue what's going on !

Comment: No I don't have any .idea directories in A or B